# Pre Populating a HTML form text fields from a url

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have been searching the internet, and I can't seem to find how to pre populate the text fields in a html form. I need the link to be dynamically changing, so different people can have links to pre populate the form. I have tried using links such as

*website_here/form.html?form_id=form&Name=Dave&Username=dave124*

and

*form_here.html?Name=Dave*

but neither of these work with my form. The form's id is form and the id's of the text fields are all different. I think this may involve Javascript because I have seen a few examples, but none of them work for me. Would someone be able to help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does setting the `value` attribute of your form's `input` tags within your HTML solve your problem?

So:

```
<form>
  <input value="Dave" name="Name"><br>
  <input value="dave124" name="Username">
</form>
```

Then, depending on what info you're using to base the dynamic content off of, you could use javascript to dynamically change value to whatever you need it to be. This would be easier to explain if I knew what info you're basing the dynamic changes off of.

Comment: The values of my textboxes have to be clear, but thanks for your help!

Comment: So you basically want AutoFill on your website? Sounds a little like you're trying to remake the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Use Post Method when submitting your form and you can echo them out to URL in your Form Action then you can use $_REQUEST or $_GET in your second form to echo as default value for the textboxes.